# Why both are called object?

Tags: oop, class, object, dll

Is there any relationship between the term `object` as an output of compiling/assembling (like:Shared Object files) and `object` as in OOP languages (an instance of a class). Why both are called `object`? What is the term `object` in computer science and how it can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No ... there is no relationship between these things. The word object is overloaded in every aspect of English and software is not an exception.

The object file (.o file) is called this only because that is what it has been called for 40+ years ([See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249945/what-is-object-in-object-file-and-why-is-it-called-this-way)); well before the idea of object oriented programming (OOP). OOP is called as such because it is a programming style which groups ideas/functionalities into objects ([See Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)).